# log4j2 IfLastModified condition in a Delete action is not interpreting age duration correctly

Tags: java, log4j2

I can't seem to get the **IfLastModified** condition in my log4j **Delete** action to properly interpret an age set in months. It keeps using it as minutes.

I have this Delete action in my log4j XML configuration file.

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy>
   <Delete basePath="${logging.dir}" maxDepth="1">
      <IfFileName glob="framework-${hostName}-*.log" />
      <IfLastModified age="2m" />
   </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

Unfortunately, it keeps using the age as minutes as seen from the logs:

```
createDeleteAction(basePath="./build/logs", followLinks="false", maxDepth="1", testMode="false", PathSorter=null, ={IfFileName(glob:framework-SY4-9CMY2W2-*.log), IfLastModified(age=PT2M)}, ScriptCondition=null, Configuration...
```

According to the Duration specification
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
"To resolve ambiguity, "P1M" is a one-month duration and "PT1M" is a one-minute duration (note the time designator, T, that precedes the time value)"

I tried specifying the age using different Duration formats but the same result.

```
<IfLastModified age="P2m" />
...
<IfLastModified age="P2M" />
```

I know I can specify 60D but I'm wondering why I can't use months duration.

I am using log4j 2.12.1

Furthermore, I suspected it could be because the filePattern was in minutes.

```
filePattern="${logging.dir}/framework-${hostName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log"
```

However, that did not have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j2 Duration object does not support month format in Duration. That must be the reason for this behaviour. It is documented here in API Documentation -

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/Duration.html

> Simplified implementation of the ISO-8601 Durations standard. The supported format is PnDTnHnMnS, with 'P' and 'T' optional. Days are considered to be exactly 24 hours.
>
> Similarly to the java.time.Duration class, this class does not support
> year or month sections in the format. This implementation does not
> support fractions or negative values.

Comment: I think you found the reason. Thanks.